# Get Limited Records For Sub Query Each Result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to query some data from SQL Server 2012 using sub query. I am trying to get first 3 records for each Id returned by Sub Query but I am not getting the idea how to do so for now I write this query: 
`Select * from Student Where TeacherId in (Select TeacherId from Teacher)`

I am not sure if this is achievable by using such query or do I have to write a function or any thing else ?
Any Suggestions would be great and sorry for my bad explanation skills.

Comment: you just wan tto display first 10 rows according to each id ?

Comment: yes that is kind of thing i am looking for

Comment: can you atleast show the  data and structure of table and expected result, please?

Comment: it is simple like i have a teacher table with teacherid and Name and a student table with col studentid, studentName and teacherid as i query data from student on the bases of teacherid i want the query to return only first 3 students against each teacherid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess  you want the `top 3` rows for each ids, not `top 3` rows for entire result set

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.TeacherId ORDER BY ?) Seq 
    FROM Student s
    INNER JOIN Teacher t ON t.TeacherId = s.TeacherId
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE Seq between 1 AND 3
```

`?` placeholder requires column_name to generate the sequence_number to get the result with boundary of 1 to 3 .

Comment: thanks for the answer but i get the idea from @tim Biegeleisen just change the Where clause from rn=3 to rn<=3 as you did the right answer i accepted yours thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You should join the `Teacher` to `Student` table, and then use an analytic function to get the first there records for each teacher:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        s.*, t.TeacherId, t.TeacherName,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.TeacherId ORDER BY some_col) rn
    FROM Teacher t
    INNER JOIN Student s
        ON t.TeacherId = s.TeacherId
) t
WHERE rn = 3;
```

I assume that there is a column in one of the two tables `some_col` which you want to use for ordering.  It does not make much sense to speak of the first three records without also defining some ordering.

Comment: thanks for giving me the idea how to do so Thank You Very Much i just change the where clause from rn = 3 to rn <= 3